# Repeating function first time through

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I am running the following code and it loops through it with an output, but then goes to the 'elif' statement skipping the if statement the first time through.  After the second time through, even if I give it the wrong answer, it stops.  How can I get it to repeat with a new set of random numbers for an incorrect guess, but then accept it if it is correct?

```
from random import randint



def solve():
    a = randint(0,10)
    b = randint(0,10)
    total = a + b
    print(str(a) + ' + ' + str(b) + ' =')
    guess = input()
    if (guess == total):
        print("Correct")
    elif (guess != total):
        print('Try again')
        a = randint(0,10)
        b = randint(0,10)
        total = a + b
        print(str(a) + ' + ' + str(b) + ' =')
        guess = input()


solve()
```

Comment: Why a -1 it's a legitimate question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input returns a string it would never be equal to an integer

```
def solve():
    a = randint(0, 10)
    b = randint(0, 10)
    total = a + b
    print(str(a) + ' + ' + str(b) + ' =')
    guess = int(input())
    if (guess == total):
        print("Correct")
    elif (guess != total):
        print('Try again')
        a = randint(0, 10)
        b = randint(0, 10)
        total = a + b
        print(str(a) + ' + ' + str(b) + ' =')
        guess = int(input())

solve()
```

Your final code should be something like:

```
def solve():
    while True:
        a = randint(0, 10)
        b = randint(0, 10)
        total = a + b
        print(str(a) + ' + ' + str(b) + ' =')
        guess = int((input()))
        if guess == total:
            print("Correct")
            break
        print('Try again')
```

Comment: That makes sense.  I thought about the while later, but still couldn't get it.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an infinite while loop(while loop with a condition which always evaluates as True).
eg.

```
while True:
    # Do something
```

Also, break the flow using `break` keyword whenever after it meets the required condition.

```
while True:
    # code
    if condition:
        break
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't see that.

Comment: I removed the conflicting code snippet. 
BTW, I posted before you about how to make an infinite loop.

Answer (score -1):

`input()` always returns a string. if you want to compare input to a number, you have to convert input to an integer.

instead of`guess = input()`, you should use`guess = int(input())`

that's why your code skips the `if` statement, string will never be equal to int.